# Quiero captruar un valor de tipo Date en mi pagina

Tags: javascript

//Yo estoy tratando de calcular el cumpleaños del usuario, con un input y capturar ese valor, y así poder decirle al usuario cuanto falta para su cumpleaños

Al momento de yo querer capturar con querySelector, desde un script diferente al principal, solo me acepta pasarle como parametro si lo escribo directamente desde la función cuando la llamo en el principal, ej:

```
 d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
countDown("#text1", "2023/08/31", "#input2", "#btnAccept", "#text2")})
```

Pero si le paso con el ID, donde quiero capturar el valor que el usuario me digite, ej:

```
 d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
countDown("#text1", "#input1", "#input2", "#btnAccept", "#text2")})
```

Me sale NaN.
Luego en el Script donde se desarrolla para calcular su cumpleaños, es este:

```
const d = document;
export function countDown(text1, input1, input2, btnAccept, text2){
const $input1 = d.querySelector(input1).value,
t = new Date($input1).getTime();
    d.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if(e.target.matches(btnAccept)){
                let getTime = setInterval(() => {
                let now = new Date().getTime(),
                    limitDate = t - now;
            //console.log(limitDate)
                let days = Math.floor(limitDate / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) ,
                    hours = ("0" + Math.floor(limitDate % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (1000 * 60 * 60))).slice(-2),
                    minutes = ("0" + Math.floor(limitDate % (1000 * 60 * 60) / (1000 * 60))).slice(-2),
                    seconds = ("0" + Math.floor(limitDate % (1000 * 60) / (1000))).slice(-2);
                d.querySelector(text2).innerHTML = `<h3>Faltan:${days} dias ${hours} horas ${minutes} minutos ${seconds} segundos para mi cumple :D </h3>`;
        
                if(limitDate< 0){
                    clearInterval(getTime);
                    d.querySelector(text2).innerHTML = `<h3>${finalMessage}</h3>`;
                }
            }, 1000);
            
        }
    })}
```

y el input a final de cuentas es este:

```
<input type="text" id="input1" name="date" required>
```

Y bueno, he tratado de todo y leyendo en diferentes foros, pero al momento de yo pasarle por teclado el cumpleaños, me sale NaN el resultado. Solo si le paso como parametro (como lo hice arriba en el 2023/08/31), me calcula su valor.

```
<div class="contCountdown">
                <input type="date" id="input1" name="date" required >
                <small>Formato: dd/mm/aaaa</small>
                <br><br>
                <svg style="width: 24; height: 24; fill: none;"></svg>
                <input type="text" id="input2">
                <small>Escribe aquí el mensaje a mostrar</small>
                <br><br>
                <button id="btnAccept" type="submit">Aceptar</button>
                <p id="text1">dd</p>
                <p id="text2"></p>
            </div>
```

Este es el html, y el resultado seria así para mostrar al usuario:

```
`<h3>Faltan:171 dias 10 horas 05 minutos 15 segundos para mi cumple :D </h3>`
```

Comment: podrias agregar tu codigo html, que deseas hacer  y cual seria el resultado esperado?

Comment: Ahi edite el código bro, miralo :)

Comment: Tu código está incompleto, de donde sale la variable `t` ??  Yo lo completé y ordené y me funciona bien

Comment: La variable T esta capturando el input1, hice eso, porque pensé en capturar el valor que envia el usuario y guardarlo en la variable $input1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo ordené mínimamente tu código y funciona. Aquí una prueba de porque el orden importa.

```js
const d = document;
btnAccept.addEventListener("click", start);

function start(){
  let t = new Date(d.getElementById("input1").value).getTime();
  let div = d.getElementById("text2");
  let finalMessage = d.getElementById("input2").value;
  
  let getTime = setInterval(() => {
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    let limitDate = t - now;
    if(limitDate< 0)
    {
       clearInterval(getTime);
       div.innerHTML = `<h3>${finalMessage}</h3>`;
    }
    else{
        div.innerHTML = getText(limitDate)
    }
    
   },1000);
}

    
function getText(limitDate){   
  let days = Math.floor(limitDate / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) ,
      hours = ("0" + Math.floor(limitDate % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (1000 * 60 * 60))).slice(-2),
      minutes = ("0" + Math.floor(limitDate % (1000 * 60 * 60) / (1000 * 60))).slice(-2),
      seconds = ("0" + Math.floor(limitDate % (1000 * 60) / (1000))).slice(-2);
  return `<h3>Faltan:${days} dias ${hours} horas ${minutes} minutos ${seconds} segundos para mi cumple :D </h3>`;

}
```

```html
<div class="contCountdown">
    <input type="date" id="input1" name="date" required >
    <small>Formato: dd/mm/aaaa</small>
    <br><br>
    <svg style="width: 24; height: 24; fill: none;"></svg>
    <input type="text" id="input2">
    <small>Escribe aquí el mensaje a mostrar</small>
    <br><br>
    <button id="btnAccept" type="submit">Aceptar</button>
    <p id="text1">dd</p>
    <p id="text2"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohh, vaya bro, muchas gracias por tu aclaración, tendré mucho más cuidado al distribuir la lógica.. Eres un crack:)